# How should I improve this question?

Tags: discussion

I asked if there is anything in Islam for killing atheists.

[Does Islam Requires/Encourage/Condone Killing Atheists](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51884/does-islam-requires-encourage-condone-killing-atheists)

It's downvoted.

The question mentions why this is "worth questioning". Namely there are laws in Iran and Malaysia, which are muslims countries.

I met with a muslim that think it should be okay/justified to kill atheists.

I wonder if killing atheists is justified in islam?

Or is there any islamic mazbah that says yap sic them.